# How can I change the size of an iframe from inside?

Tags: html, iframe

I am developing with jquery and I stumbled with the next problem: I added an IFrame inside the main page and I want to re size them from inside. I tried some ideas but without success.

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="myframe" src="frame.html" width="100px" height="100px"></frame>
    </body>
</html>
```

frame.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IFrame</title>
        <script>
            document.width = 500;
            document.height = 500;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>My IFrame</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you create an `IFRAME` the browser automatically adds a `'window'` object for the IFRAME inside the `'window'` object of main page.

You need to change the size of the `IFRAME` instead of the size of the document.

Try this code:

For `JavaScript`:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('myframe').width = '500px';
window.parent.document.getElementById('myframe').height = '500px';
```

And for `jQuery`:

```
$('#myframe', window.parent.document).width('500px');
$('#myframe', window.parent.document).height('500px');
```

Comment: I'm guessing this can't be done from a different domain, right?

Comment: Yes, different domains fails with the following message in Chrome: `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://anotherwebsite.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://mywebsite.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

Comment: I don't get that error. As a proof of concept: http://jperelli.com.ar/covert_channel_iframe_resize/

Comment: @jperreli you are including the iframe from a subdomain on your domain, that's probably why it works?

Answer (score 17):

If both pages are on the same domain (or even subdomain if you set document.domain maybe, did not test it) you can simply set it from javascript (or jQuery):

```html
window.parent.document.getElementById('myframe').width = '500px';
```

If you the pages are on different domains one solution would be to to add an event listener in the page that is calling the iFrame (credits to Marty Mulligan):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
 <script src="/js/jquery/js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
   debugger;
    var iframe = $("#myIframe");
    var eventName = e.data[0];
    var data = e.data[1];
    switch(eventName) {
   case 'setHeight':
     iframe.height(data);
     break;
    }
  }, false);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://hofvanzeeland.net/frame.html" width="100px" height="100px" border="1"></frame>
</body>
</html>
```

and trigger it from the iFrame content (frame.html):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IFrame</title>  
        <script>            
   function resize() {
     var height = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollHeight;
     window.parent.postMessage(["setHeight", height], "*"); 
   }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>My IFrame</h2>
  <a href="#" onclick="resize()">Click me</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very well explained !! Worked for me !

Comment: Yo huge security risk here to be aware of - via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage):

**tl;dr** If you do not expect to receive messages from other sites, do not add any event listeners for message events, always verify the senders identity, and Always specify an exact target origin, not *, when you use postMessage to send data to other windows.

Answer (score -1):

```
function setHeight() {
    parent.document.getElementById('the-iframe-id').style.height = document['body'].offsetHeight + 'px';
}
```

Another way using `Javascript`

```
document.getElementById("ifr").height= "500px";
document.getElementById("ifr").width= "500px";
```

[**DEMO JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/PmBrd/199/)

Comment: This is not from inside.